# Unable to show primary key value in rdlc report

Tags: model-view-controller, report, primary-key, rdlc

I am unable to show primary key value in rdlc report. 
During displaying informations in rdlc report, I can't view values from primary key field, which is referred by some foreign key table.

Comment: What is rdlc report? What exactly are you trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: There is no possible way this question can be answered given the limited information provided.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i'm using Rotativa to Print PDF report from URL instead of RDLC report or from Partial View Model by Rotativa also , and u got your Report ready !